# PHP 7. Передача параметров в деструктор

Tags: php

Возможно ли передавать параметры в деструктор и какие существуют при этом нюансы?

```
    class People 
    {
      public $name;
      public $age;
      public $sex;

      public function __construct($name, $age, $sex)
      {
         $this->name = $name;
         $this->age = $age;
         $this->sex = $sex;

         echo "It`s called function __construct <br>";
      }

      public function __destruct($name, $age, $sex)
      {
        echo $this->name . "is destroyed";
      }
    }

     $people = new People("Ivan", 20, "male");
```

Comment: Нюанс в том, что деструкторы вызываются автоматически по окончанию обработки скрипта. И вызываться они будут без параметров.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У деструктора нет параметров. В том числе, их недопустимо указывать, иначе при попытке объявить класс с таким деструктором будет сгенерирован `fatal error`:

> Destructor foo::__destruct() cannot take arguments

С другой стороны у деструктора есть доступ ко всем свойствам объекта. Если для особой логики по удалению объекта из памяти вам недостаточно состояния этого самого объекта - вы что-то делаете весьма неправильно.